# Client request fails due to CSRF check in Spring Boot test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, csrf

I have a spring boot application and I'm trying to write an integration test that will check that everything works from the client request to the server response including DB queries, etc.

Here is my `@SpringBootTest`:

```
@Nested
inner class Contacts {
        @Test
        fun `should fetch contacts`() {
            val query = "{ contacts { id contact title type }}"
            val client = MonoGraphQLClient.createWithWebClient(WebClient.create("http://localhost:$port/graphql")) // Effectively just a POST request to an endpoint of application

            val response = client.reactiveExecuteQuery(query).block()

            val contacts: MutableList<*> = response!!.extractValueAsObject("contacts[*]", MutableList::class.java)

            println(contacts)
        }
}
```

But surprisingly this fails with the following error: `Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:54192/graphql`.

This is strange because I disabled csrf in my application like this:

```
http
    .cors()
    .and()
    .csrf().disable()
```

In fact this has nothing to do with netflix dgs, I think, because any POST request fails with such an error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: One thing remains unclear: is graphql on same port/the same application as you test? ([like here](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/getting-started/)->cannot reproduce, `csrf().disable()` has "few effect"), otherwise: it would come from the (`$port`) backend...

Comment: @xerx593 didn't quite get you, do you mean that graphql endpoint is exposed through another port? No, it isn't. It is exposed through the same port as ordinary rest endpoints.  
By this  `like here->cannot reproduce` did you mean that you cannot reproduce the issue I face?